# Change the value of a Text widget by animating the opacity down to 0 and back to 1 in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, opacity, flutter-animation

How can I do this in Flutter:

I want to update the value of a `Text` widget when a `FloatingActionButton` is pressed:

- Animate the opacity of the `Text` widget down to 0 for a duration of 1 second (hide the old value)
- Change the value of the `Text` widget (set a new value - `setState`?)
- Animate the opacity of the `Text` widget up to 1 for a duration of 1 second (show the new value)

Can I do this using `AnimatedOpacity`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, don't forget to await before calling the second setState to reanimate the text back.

```
  String text = 'Text Initial';
  double opacity = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              opacity = 0.0;
            });
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
            setState(() {
              text = 'New Text';
              opacity = 1.0;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: AnimatedOpacity(
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            opacity: opacity,
            child: Text(text),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```